# AspNet Parser bug validation: Render controls (<% %>) within Head runat=server can fail to be parsed as code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for validation here.

Some initial definitions I use:
"gator tags" are the <% %> tags for executing 'at render' code

Given the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <!-- meta description --><meta runat="server" id="meta_description" name="description" content="" visible="false" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="<%=Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ASPNet Head runat=server parser bug.</h1>
    <p>Inspect the source and look for &lt;link rel="canonical" and see that you have the Render code enclosed with &lt;% %&gt; being sent to the browser.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

First, take notice of the render code in the `<link rel="canonical" href="<%= Context.Request.AbsoluteUri %>" />`.  This is intended to output the AbsoluteUri for the current page *(please refrain from the distraction about link rel=canonical semantics... I acknowledge this may not be the ideal way to do this)*

When you run this code, the HTML sent to the browser is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- meta description --><link rel="canonical" href="&lt;%=Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>" /><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>ASPNet Head runat=server parser bug.</h1>
    <p>Inspect the source and look for &lt;link rel="canonical" and see that you have the Render code enclosed with &lt;% %&gt; being sent to the browser.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notice how the render code within <% %> is output into the HTML stream, and not executed?**

The major bug I see is that the ASP.Net parser doesn't adequately kick into Code Parsing state for the link tag, but instead grabs the whole string `"<%= Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>"` and shoves that into the (string)Href property for HtmlLink.  (You can verify this by adding <%asdf%> somewhere on the page to see the ASP.Net parser's generated source and search for 'AbsoluteUri').

The odd thing is that Head runat=Server seems to kick the ASP.Net parser into a state where every tag, with or without 'runat=server', gets built as a server control.  This has several side effects that I've noticed over the years, like whitespace slamming and others.

**When you remove runat="server" from the HEAD tag, it works properly.** The expected behavior is the `Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` is properly emitted as: `http://localhost:5678/HeadParserBug.aspx`

I don't want this to be a discussion, but a validation by stackoverflow community of the problem.  Can the ASP.Net community at large validate this find?  Thanks.

Comment: It is something about link tag itself. Because if you remove runat="server" from head tag and add it to link tag directly then same thing happens.